What does the negative number of continuous variables in the gurobi stats of pyomo mean?
When gurobi is interfaced by pyomo with either solver_io='python' or solver_io='direct' the gurobi stats do sometimes display a negative amount of continuous variables. If the solver_io parameter isn't set or solver_io='lp'is used, this problem does not occur. As far as I've experienced, this phenomenon occurs when the number of binary variables outnumber the number of continous variables (hence the number in the stats states exactly the difference). Furthermore, it doesn't occur if instead of the binary an NonNegativeInteger with bounds=(0,1) is used.
So my question is, does this have any meaning I should be taken care of (as this might indicate model inconsistency or similar) or can this issue be ignored, because this that is a flaw in the pyomo-gurobi interface?
Here is a small example for reproduction:
import pyomo.environ as pyo

# create concrete model
model = pyo.ConcreteModel()

# define binary variable as vector
model.b = pyo.Var(range(5), within=pyo.Binary)  # 5 binary variables

# define continuous variable as vector
model.x = pyo.Var(range(2), within=pyo.NonNegativeReals)  # 5 continuous variables

# define simple constraint
model.con1 = pyo.Constraint(expr=sum(model.b[i] for i in range(5)) >= 3)   # at least 3 of the binary variables must be 1

# selecte solver and solve
solver = pyo.SolverFactory('gurobi', solver_io='direct')
result = solver.solve(model)

# print gurobi stats
print(result)

output:
Problem: 
- Name: unknown
  Lower bound: 0.0
  Upper bound: 0.0
  Number of objectives: 1
  Number of constraints: 1
  Number of variables: 7
  Number of binary variables: 5
  Number of integer variables: 5
  Number of continuous variables: -3
  Number of nonzeros: 5
  Sense: minimize
  Number of solutions: 1
Solver: 
- Name: Gurobi 11.03
  Status: ok
  Wallclock time: 0.0
  Termination condition: optimal
  Termination message: Model was solved to optimality (subject to tolerances), and an optimal solution is available.
Solution: 
- number of solutions: 0
  number of solutions displayed: 0


I guess it's a flaw in the wrapper and it probably does infer #cont = #ALL - #bin - #int but double counts binaries as bin as well as int: 7 - 5 - 5 = -3. Seems there is already a bug-ticket (where my formula also works out in the example) although without activity.

number of solutions: 0 is also strange.

yes, number of solutions: 0 is also odd, since I get values for b if I print print(model.b.get_values())
